# innerText is different in a cloned node

Tags: javascript, html, dom

(**NOTE:** This question isn't the same as the similar one above, as it is about differences between attached and detached DOM trees.)

A simple bit of HTML containing a DIV with no whitespace between its elements:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
    <div><h1>The Title</h1><p>A paragraph.</p><p>A second paragraph.</p></div>
  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript">

   const div = document.querySelector("div");

   console.log(div.innerText);

   const clone = div.cloneNode(true);
   console.log(clone.innerText);

   document.body.appendChild(clone);
   console.log(clone.innerText);

  </script>
</html>
```

I output `innerText` to the console three times.

The first time is that of the original DIV:

```
The Title

A paragraph.

A second paragraph.
```

The second is that of the cloned DIV, which I would expect to be the same, but is:

```
The TitleA paragraph.A second paragraph.​
```

The third is again that of the cloned DIV, but after it has been added to the document, now what I would expect it to be:

```
The Title

A paragraph.

A second paragraph.
```

Why is the spacing different when it is not part of the document?

Comment: Are you looking at `innerText` or `innerHTML`? Your title says one thing, your question body another...

Comment: Sorry, yes, `innerText`.  The code is right; the description is what had a typo - thanks @romellem for the edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a quirk of [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) for *detached* DOM nodes:

> If the element itself is not [being rendered](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#being-rendered) (for example, is detached from the document or is hidden from view), the returned value is the same as the [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property.

This is because `innerText` takes CSS into account (in this case, the `display: block` properties of the tags to insert new lines (`\n`)).

From the [algorithm for computing `innerText`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#rendered-text-collection-steps), step 9 says:

> If node's used value of 'display' is block-level or 'table-caption', then append 1 (a required line break count) at the beginning and end of items.

As you see, after you insert the cloned node into the DOM, then `innerText` returns what the original node did because it is able to compute those CSS properties:

```js
const div = document.querySelector("div");

console.log("Original, innerText:", JSON.stringify(div.innerText));
console.log("Original, textContent:", JSON.stringify(div.textContent));

const clone = div.cloneNode(true);
console.log("Detached clone, innerText:", JSON.stringify(clone.innerText));
console.log("Detached clone, textContent:", JSON.stringify(clone.textContent));

document.body.appendChild(clone);

console.log("Attached clone, innerText:", JSON.stringify(clone.innerText));
console.log("Attached clone, textContent:", JSON.stringify(clone.textContent));
```

```html
<div><h1>The Title</h1><p>A paragraph.</p><p>A second paragraph.</p></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that makes a lot of sense.  I now need to investigate another issue I'm having, where some of the cloned node's children have non-empty `innerHTML` and `textContent` properties, but empty `innerText` properties!  I thought this must be a bug in my Firefox, but Chrome is doing it too!  Probably one for a separate question.

Comment: UPDATE: I eventually realised that this was another quirk of `innerText` where some of the elements had opacity of 0 and so their innerText was empty but the `textContent` wasn't!